# Return DTO object that contains more than one entity from the service layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper, repository-pattern

I am developing an .net multi tier application using repository pattern. My data access layer which implements the repository pattern has methods that return the data to Service layer layer which in turn returns data to the web api layer. Currently I have written methods that will return either Customer information or Order information. I need to also write methods that will return CustomerOrder information. I think the best place is to write it in the service layer but not sure how to go about it. I have created a DTO object in the service layer which contains fields from both the Customer and Order class. Is the service layer the best place to write this logic. I think I would have to populate the Dto object in the service layer and return that object to the presentation layer. Could somebody show me the way.

**Entity layer**

```
 public class Customers
    {


        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public Address Address { get; set; }

        public int AddressId { get; set; }


        public ICollection<Orders> Orders { get; set; }

    }
    public class Orders
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
        public int? OrderNumber { get; set; }

        public Customers Customers { get; set; }

        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ProductOrder> ProductOrders { get; set; }
    }

   public class Address
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Address1 { get; set; }

        public string Address2 { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public State State { get; set; }

        public int StateId { get; set; }


        public ICollection<Customers> Customers { get; set; }


        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    }
```

**DataAccess Layer**

```
 public class CustomerRepository : RepositoryBase<Customers>, ICustomerRepository
    {
        public CustomerRepository(IDbFactory dbFactory)
            : base(dbFactory) { }



        public IEnumerable<Customers> GetAllCustomers()
        {
            return (from customer in this.DbContext.Customers
                    select customer).ToList();
        }

    }

    public interface ICustomerRepository : IRepository<Customers>
    {
        IEnumerable<Customers> GetAllCustomers();

    }


 public class OrderRepository : RepositoryBase<Orders>, IOrderRepository
    {
        public OrderRepository(IDbFactory dbFactory)
            : base(dbFactory) {}

        public IEnumerable<Orders> GetAllOrders()
        {
            return (from order in this.DbContext.Orders
                    select order).ToList();
        }

    }

    public interface IOrderRepository : IRepository<Orders>
    {
        IEnumerable<Orders> GetAllOrders();
    }
```

**Service layer**

```
    public interface ICustomerService
        {
            IEnumerable<Customers> GetCustomers();
        }

        public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
        {
            private readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;
            private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

            public CustomerService(ICustomerRepository customerRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
            {
                this._customerRepository = customerRepository;
                this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            }


            public IEnumerable<Customers> GetCustomers()
            {
                return _customerRepository.GetAll();
            }




 public interface IOrderService
        {
            IEnumerable<Orders> GetOrders();

        }

        public class OrderService : IOrderService
        {
            private readonly IOrderRepository _orderRepository;
            private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

            public OrderService(IOrderRepository orderRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
            {
                this._orderRepository = orderRepository;
                this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            }
           }

            public IEnumerable<Orders> GetOrders()
            {
                return _orderRepository.GetAll();
            }
           }
```

**Dto object in the service layer**

```
  public class CustomerDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

    }



public class OrderDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
    public int? OrderNumber { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerOrderDto
{
    public CustomerDto Customer { get; set; }
    public OrderDto Order { get; set; }

}
```

**Mapping (Domain objects to Dto) in the service Layer**

```
public class DomainToDtoMapping : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return "DomainToDtoMapping"; }
    }

    [Obsolete]
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Customers, CustomerDto>();
        CreateMap<Address, AddressDto>();
        CreateMap<Orders, OrderDto>();
        CreateMap<OrdersDetails, OrderDetailsDto>();
        CreateMap<State, StateDto>();


        CreateMap<CustomerDto, CustomerOrderDto>();
        CreateMap<AddressDto, CustomerOrderDto>();
        CreateMap<OrderDto, CustomerOrderDto>();
        CreateMap<OrderDetailsDto, CustomerOrderDto>();
        CreateMap<State, CustomerOrderDto>();

    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally, your service layer would return only DTOs and you would use, say, Automapper to map Database entities to DTOs. Now you can evolve the service interface independently from the database layer and can combine database entities into DTOs to return from the service layer.

Comment: Apart from complexity, the question is, what do you gain with an additional repositorylayer...

Comment: Man, you really need MediatR. All those layer objects aren't doing you any favors with all this. Collapse those layers! https://vimeo.com/131633177

Comment: Are you still working on a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered implementing the [**Composite Pattern**](http://www.dofactory.com/net/composite-design-pattern)?

Your `CustomerOrderDto` would contain a `CustomerDto` and an `OrderDto` class. Like so:

```
public class CustomerOrderDto
{
    public CustomerDto Customer {get; set;}
    public OrderDto Order {get; set;}
}
```

Implementing this pattern would give the following advantages:

1. Any future changes to the `CustomerDto` or `OrderDto` would automatically be part of the `CustomerOrderDto`.
2. The code for mapping data to the `dto` classes can be reused for mapping a single `dto` entity as well as the `CustomerOrderDto'.

The code for mapping the Entity classes to the DTO classes should be in your service layer.

Mapping the Customer entity to the CustomerDto entity:

```
    internal static CustomerDto Map(Customer entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

        CustomerDto dto = new CustomerDto();
        try
        {
            dto.Id = entity.Id;
            dto.FirstName = entity.FirstName;
            dto.LastName = entity.LastName;
            dto.Gender = entity.Gender;
            dto.Email = entity.Email;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string errMsg = String.Format("Map(entity). Error mapping a Customer entity to DTO. Id: {0}.", entity.Id);
            //LOG ERROR
        }

        return dto;
    }
```

Have you completed the repository layer for retrieving the Composite CustomerOrder entities? I see you have the completed repository code for `GetAllCustomers()` and `GetAllOrders()`.

Comment: So do you mean using the composite pattern, I can simply create a method in the service class that would return this CustomerOrderDto and the automapper will take care of the mappings

Comment: How will I populate this DTO before I send it to the presentation layer

Comment: In the same manner you populate the `CustomerDto` and `OrderDto` entities today. You would simply send each class to its relevant mapping function. I may be missing something, but I do not see the two mapping methods in your question. If you can add those (or point them out to me, if they are already there) I would be able to answer your question more specifically.

Comment: The only mapping that I have done is the domain to dto mapping as shown in my post above.As per your suggestion , I have created individual dto's and composite dto. What do I need to do next. Could you show me an example on how to populate the customerorderdto object.

Comment: I'd be happy to. Could you help me out by providing the mapping function for either the `CustomerDto` or `OrderDto` entities?

Comment: Are you referring to this  public class DomainToDtoMapping : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return "DomainToDtoMapping"; }
    }

    [Obsolete]
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Customers, CustomerOrderDto>();
        CreateMap<Address, CustomerOrderDto>();
        CreateMap<Orders, CustomerOrderDto>();
        CreateMap<OrdersDetails, CustomerOrderDto>();

    }
}

Comment: Or are you referring to something like what codelover has suggested. If thats the case , I am struggling with that

Comment: I have updated my answer with some sample mapping code. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Shai, I am using automapper to map the entities with Dtos. Do you need a one to one mapping like you have shown in your answer. Please see my post above. i have used auto mapper in the service layer to do the mapping.

Comment: Sorry if I am being a bit obtuse, but by "do you need", do you mean "does it require" or do you mean "do you need an example"?

Comment: Sorry Shai for not being clear. I meant does it require as the mapping is already done the automapper. What I am looking for his how is automapper mapping used while returning the Dto's from the service layer..So I am referring to this method for example public IEnumerable<CustomerDto> GetCustomers()
        {
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129873/discussion-between-shai-cohen-and-tom).

Comment: Any luck Shai as discussed earlier in the chat

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public interface IOrderService
    {
        IEnumerable<CustomerOrderDto> GetOrders();
    }

 public IEnumerable<CustomerOrderDto> GetOrders()
    {
        List<CustomerOrderDto> customerOrderList = new List<CustomerOrderDto>();

        foreach (var item in customerOrderList)
        {
            CustomerOrderDto customerOrder = new CustomerOrderDto();
            //fields mapping

            customerOrderList.Add(customerOrder);
        }


        return customerOrderList;
    }
```

The best method for mapping is linq or this.You shouldn't use Automapper because it's so slow.

Comment: How will I map the Customer, Order , Address entity to CustomerOrderDTO here

Comment: Create dto for each entity and do mapping.

Comment: I have updated the post to show the use of AutoMapper. Whats the benefit of AutoMapper if its slow. I see a lot of people recommending AutoMapper.

Comment: I don't use automapper for mapping process.The best performing use linq but if you want to use automapper.For each entity class create in base class.See: Shai Cohen answer.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but it looks like you are iterating on `customerOrderList` which you just instantiated. Shouldn't you be iterating on a `DataReader` or something along those lines?

Comment: foreach (var item in _customerRepository.GetAll()).excuse me.

Comment: I don t think that automapper is too slow. See this: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/06/24/automapper-5-0-speed-increases/ and it makes the code cleaner and more readable